# MySQL get results with MySQL only

Tags: php, mysql

Say I had a MySQL table as pictured below, and I wanted to find any `product_id`'s which have the filters 2 AND 5 (so in the table this would be the product_id of 30), is this possible in MySQL? Or would I have to get product id's where the `filter_id` is 2 OR 5, and sort it in PHP?

[image: sql table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS i FROM mytable WHERE filter_id IN (2,5) GROUP BY product_id  HAVING i = 2;`

This will match any rows containing any of the required filter_ids and group together those with the same product_id.  The name i has been given to a column giving the number of rows in the group.  Assuming that every combination of product_id to filter_id will be unique then you know that any group with two rows will have matched both of the filter_ids, so the HAVING clause will finally filter out the rows that only matched one of the filter_ids.